# ListView with multiple choice

Tags: android, listview

I want to implement a `ListView` that can handle multiple choices and detect a click.
I want each list to contain a checkbox so if you click on the check box it will remember the choice, and if you click on the text in the line it will go to another activity.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `ListView` with a custom `Adapter`. here is a code for a list view with a check box and a clickable item:

```
private class MySecondAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MiniTask>
{   
    private ArrayList<MiniTask> list;

    public MySecondAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<MiniTask> miniTaskList) 
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, miniTaskList);
         this.list = new ArrayList<MiniTask>();
         this.list.addAll(miniTaskList);
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        miniTask = miniTaskList.get(position);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.check_list_item_new, null);

            holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemTitle);
            holder.commentsPicturesButton = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iAddCommetOrPicture);
            holder.commentsPicturesButton.setTag(position);
            holder.commentsPicturesButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PicturesAndCommentsActivity.class);
                     intent.putExtra(TasksListActivity.KEY_ID, task.getId());
                     intent.putExtra("mini_task_text", miniTask.getTitle());
                     startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            holder.selected = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cbCheckListItem);
            holder.selected.setTag(position);
            holder.selected.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {    
                    {                               
                        Log.d(TAG, "pressed the checkbox: " + v.getId() + " in position: " + position + " tag: " +v.getTag() +" and item from array: " + miniTaskList.get(position) );
                        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) v;
                        miniTaskList.get(position).setSelected(checkbox.isChecked());   
                        numOfCheckedMiniTasks = 0;
                        for(int i=0;i<miniTaskList.size();i++)
                        {
                             miniTask = miniTaskList.get(i);
                             if(miniTask.isSelected())
                             {
                                numOfCheckedMiniTasks ++;
                             }
                        }
                        int percent = (int)(numOfCheckedMiniTasks * 100.0f) / miniTaskList.size();
                        Log.d(TAG, "the percentage is: " +percent);
                        tasksRepository.get(tasksRepository.indexOf(task)).setMiniTasksPercentageComplete(percent);
                    }
                }
            });     
        }

        holder.title.setText(miniTask.getTitle());
        holder.selected.setChecked(miniTask.isSelected());
        return convertView;
    }
```

and the `ViewHolder`:

```
    static class ViewHolder 
{
     TextView title;
     CheckBox selected;
     ImageView commentsPicturesButton;
}
```

and the row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:background="@drawable/try2"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/cbCheckListItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/checkbox_checklist_selector" 
        android:button="@drawable/checkbox_checklist_selector" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvItemTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="13dp"
        android:text="@string/checklist_item_string"
        android:textColor="@color/my_darker_gray" />
  </LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:paddingTop="6.5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iAddCommetOrPicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@drawable/comment_or_photo_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/comment_or_photo_icon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Emil_Adz what is the meaning of the type MiniTask

Comment: it's an object i used to populated the list, you can replace it with string.

Comment: and my XML should be like this?
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/browser_image"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/folder" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/browser_file_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

Comment: 1. never add code as a comment as no one will ever understand it or even try to read it, if you want to add additional code just edit you question.
2. I have added the single row layout.

Comment: in this code you create an onClickListener for each one of the checkbox right? that means that i'll have listeners as the numbers of rows in the list view?

Comment: that the way I did it. yes.